# exp/pow that reaches those points?

Tags: functions, polynomials, exponentiation

I need a function that will reaches those points, based on X input values, such as:

```
0 => -70db
0.5 => -16.26db
1.0 => 6db
```

note: db are calculated in classic equation log10(x) * 20

so basically, it should reach:

```
0 => 0.0003162277
0.5 => 0.15381546403030347
1.0 => 1.9952623149688795
```

[This](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/l2awnnzlpx?lang=it) is my attemps using pow and exp, but without catching them:

[image]

What's the way to "curve" it and getting the desidered result?
Can be accomplished with exp/pow or do I need some sort of polynomial (horner form, etc)?

Comment: Are you looking for a function that passes through three given points? In general you will need a function with at least three adjustable parameters.

Comment: @lcv maybe. is it not possible to do it with exp or pow and adjustable scaling?